# Using querySelectorAll instead of querySelector for testing with toBeInTheDocument

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

Is it possible to use `querySelectorAll` with jest react tests rather than individually selecting each component with `querySelector` and checking that they're in the document with `toBeInTheDocument`?

For example, testing a component like this:

```
const SomeComponent = () => (
  <>
    <p id='one'>one</p>
    <p id='two'>two</p>
    <p id='three'>three</p>
  </>
)
```

Would otherwise require writing a test like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';

describe('Some Component', () => {
  it('Should render all', () => {
    const {container} = render(<SomeComponent/>);

    const one = container.querySelector('#one');
    const two = container.querySelector('#two');
    const three = container.querySelector('#three');

    expect(one).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(two).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(three).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

I have a list of numerous elements which is starting to get quite lengthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the number of the `p` element and use `for...loop` to check each one of them is in the document or not. So you don't need to assert them one by one.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { SomeComponent } from '.';

describe('Some Component', () => {
  it('Should render all', () => {
    const { container } = render(<SomeComponent />);
    const matches = container.querySelectorAll('p');
    expect(matches).toHaveLength(3);
    matches.forEach((m) => {
      expect(m).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Very logical, thank you